# A good practice for setting computed properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database, entity-framework

I am wondering what is a "good practice" for setting properties that are not mapped in the database. I am working with EF Core, but this is really more of a question of design. Imagine I have a following class:

```
class User
{

   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }

   [NotMapped]
   public string Name { get; set; }

   ...

}
```

Where `Name` would be computed after fetching the the `FirstName` and `LastName` from the database. I am trying to prevent calling the getter for `Name` without setting the property first.

I know I could do something like

```
class User
{
   ...

   private string _name = null;

   [NotMapped]
   public string Name { 

     get 
     {
        if (_name == null)
          _name = $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
        return _name;
     }

   }
   ...
}
```

But this gets really messy when multiple properties need to be set this way and when they are obtained in a more complicated way than this one-liner.

For now I wrote a function `SetAllProperties()` which sets all NotMapped properties, however I don't consider it a good solution since there is a risk of forgetting

1. To update it when new NotMapped properties are added
2. To actually call it before accessing the properties

Is an interface a way to go? How should it look like? Or is there some "standard" way of dealing with this? I wasn't able to find anything useful on this topic.

Comment: hope this would help: https://daveaglick.com/posts/computed-properties-and-entity-framework

Comment: Your code will only work if the entity has been read from the db. If you read Name just after "new User()" it will not work

Comment: @efekctive i know, it is actually a part of a login system so the user is read from the db when he logs in. that is also the place where i am computing the properties for now. i dont intend calling the user’s constructor

Comment: another thing that has occurred to me is to make a UserViewModel that would inherit from User and compute the properties there

Comment: If you need to compute them, then they behave more like a method. Turn them into methods. This will leave your properties mapping clearly,